# In a Baccarat Road Map Simulation, how do I count every row and column of the multidemensional array?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a multidimensional array which is declared like this

```
string[,] table = new string[104,15];
```

Now it has all the data that I need and I got the data to put it on the table by doing this

```
int xIndex = 0;
int yIndex = 0;
string newPreviousValue = "placeholder";

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
     newString[0] += list[i].r;
     newString[0] += ",";
}

string[] newChars = newString[0].Split(',');

foreach (string previousValue in newChars)
{
     table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is from this `Data A`

[image]

All these value of `Data B` is depending on what value of `Data A` has

> **RED** means *"The same in length"*
>
> **BLUE** means *"Not the same in length"*

[image]

So here how it works .

## PSEUDO CODE

```
//I am talking about Data A
if table[1,1] is equal to null or T then
{

    if table[1,0] and table[0,0] has the same length
    
    //Display blue circle on Data B
    display a blue circle
    
}
//I am talking about Data A
else if table[1,1] is not equal to null then
{
    compare table[0,1] and table[0,0] if they have the same length as table[1,1] and table[1,0]
    
    //Display a red circle
    display a red circle }
 }
```

If I am not clear here's the [rule](https://www.livecasinocomparer.com/live-casino-games/live-baccarat/baccarat-roadmaps/) . What I am talking about is the Big Eye Road Rules.

What I have tried so far is this

```
 //lets check for the 2nd row and 2nd column of the big road table
 if (table[1,1] == null && table[2,0] != null)
 {
     Move = true;
     if (Move)
     {
 //lets move to the 3rd row and compare if they have the same in length (1st row and 1st column)
          if (table[0, 0] != null && table[1, 0] != null)
          {
              //red circle
          }
          else
          {
               //blue circle
          }
     }
 }
```

What I want to achieve here is to count every row and column in `DATA A` if how many data's that are stored there for example

`table[0,0] to table[0,6]` has `1 data`

`table[1,0] to table[1,6]` has `1 data`

`table[2,0] to table[2,6]` has `2 data`

Just like that . Could someone help with it please. Thank you.

## EDIT

On the last part of my question I will share what I did

```
//COLUMN
for(int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); col++)
{
   int sum = 0;
   //ROW
   for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
   {
       if (table[col,row] != null)
       {
           sum++;
       }
   }
   Debug.Log("table column: " + col + " has " + sum + " data");
}
```

I can now get this

`table[0,0] to table[0,6]` has `1 data`

`table[1,0] to table[1,6]` has `1 data`

`table[2,0] to table[2,6]` has `2 data`

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are actually trying to do. You have included a link to a bad explanation of a game that you are trying to recreate, that has a lot of rules. You will need to explain clearly in your own question what functionality you are trying to recreate.

Comment: You may have code missing, but foreach (string previousValue in newChars)
{
     table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}, does not increment.

Comment: What do you mean by "have the same length".

Comment: I don't think this question can be solved in its current state. There are key pieces of information that are missing. For example what does,  table[0,0] to table[0,6] has 1 data, mean?

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper this has been solved :)

Comment: Yay! If you have time you should maybe post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); col++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        //ROW
        for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
        {
            if (table[col,row] != null)
            {
                sum++;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("table column: " + col + " has " + sum + " data");
    }
```